# How to fetch json data for dropdown in ui

Tags: java, json, selenium-webdriver

I have 3 dropdown (select classes). After the selection of 1st dropdown have to verify, `{ "IsActive" : "True" }` and continue to get the 2nd dropdown values. Could you please suggest how to retrieve the values in code.

For example:

```
{
    abc: 1,
    cbd: 2
},
{
    Isactive: true,
    data 2 : [
               abc,
               bcd
             ]
}
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.